# How to use all cores in the computer with Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

**My computer has: 24 cores, 32 GB RAM**

I have known for a while and read about that it is possible to make use of more/all cores in the computer when doing heavy tasks using `Parallel.ForEach`

But I have never quite understand how to do this exactly. I will take a chance to give my realtime example which uses a single loop that I now use which contains the below code.

**It now takes 57 seconds to execute the code.**

There are over 3 million loops/calculations that takes place in this loop.

Just giving this loop that is not possible to test from the code that I paste here since there are no memories fed to the function.

Is there a solution how to execute this code using as many cores as my computer has? (I have 24 cores in my computer)

The code returns those 2 lists:

```
List<String> minusLIST
List<String> plusLIST

public void calculationFunction(Dictionary<String, List<String>> tr1, Dictionary<String, List<ArrayList>> v1, Dictionary<String, bool> v5,
                                Dictionary<String, int> infoIndex, out List<String> minusLIST, out List<String> plusLIST)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
    double num1 = 0; double num2 = 0; double num3 = 0; double number1 = 0; double number2 = 0; double number3 = 0; double thenum1 = 0; double thenum2 = 0; double thenum3 = 0;
    double NUM1 = 0; double NUM2 = 0; double NUM3 = 0; double NUMBER1 = 0; double NUMBER2 = 0; double NUMBER3 = 0; String str = ""; String num11 = ""; String num22 = ""; String num33 = "";
    String number11 = ""; String number22 = ""; String number33 = ""; double calc1 = 0;
    minusLIST = new List<String>(); plusLIST = new List<String>();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<String, List<String>> entry in tr1) 
    {
        List<String> allparams = new List<String>(entry.Value);
        if (allparams.Count == 10)
        {
            if (v5.ContainsKey(allparams[7]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[8]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[9]))
            {
                if (v5[allparams[7]] && v5[allparams[8]] && v5[allparams[9]])
                {
                    //Calculate both calc scenarios!
                    num1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][0]; number1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][1]; thenum1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][2];
                    num2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][0]; number2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][1]; thenum2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][2];
                    num3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][0]; number3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][1]; thenum3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][2];

                    NUM1 = num1; NUM2 = num2; NUM3 = num3; NUMBER1 = number1; NUMBER2 = number2; NUMBER3 = number3;
                    if (num1 <= 0 || number1 <= 0) { NUM1 = thenum1; NUMBER1 = thenum1; }
                    if (num2 <= 0 || number2 <= 0) { NUM2 = thenum2; NUMBER2 = thenum2; }
                    if (num3 <= 0 || number3 <= 0) { NUM3 = thenum3; NUMBER3 = thenum3; }
                    if (NUM1 > 0 && NUM2 > 0 && NUM3 > 0 && NUMBER1 > 0 && NUMBER2 > 0 && NUMBER3 > 0)
                    {
                        str = ""; num11 = ""; num22 = ""; num33 = ""; number11 = ""; number22 = ""; number33 = "";
                        if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0 && number3 > 0) { } else { str = string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum1) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum2) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum3); }

                        if (num1 <= 0) { num11 = "0"; num1 = thenum1; } else { num11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num1); }
                        if (num2 <= 0) { num22 = "0"; num2 = thenum2; } else { num22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num2); }
                        if (num3 <= 0) { num33 = "0"; num3 = thenum3; } else { num33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num3); }
                        if (number1 <= 0) { number11 = "0"; number1 = thenum1; } else { number11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number1); }
                        if (number2 <= 0) { number22 = "0"; number2 = thenum2; } else { number22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number2); }
                        if (number3 <= 0) { number33 = "0"; number3 = thenum3; } else { number33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number3); }


                        //Calculate
                        if (allparams[6] == "0")
                        {
                            calc1 = ((num1 * number2 * number3) - 45) / 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            calc1 = (((num1 * number2) / number3) + 45) / 10;
                        }

                        //String
                        str = calc1 + "," + allparams[0] + " - " + allparams[1] + " - " + allparams[2] + "," +
                                                             allparams[3] + " - " + allparams[4] + " - " + allparams[5] + "," +
                                                             num11 + " / " + num22 + " / " + num33 + "," +
                                                             number11 + " / " + number22 + " / " + number33 + "," +
                                                             str + "," +
                                                             calc1 + "%";

                        if (calc1 > 0) { plusLIST.Add(str); }
                        else
                        {
                            minusLIST.Add(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a single `Parallel.ForEach` loop there. Did you try anything or at least read the documentation? I'm not sure what you are asking besides that

Comment: Yes, I thought of only paste my code that I use for a single loop. Yes I have red the documention so many times but never got a good understanding. So this is my chance to really put out a real life example and see if I can understand something from this. For example can I just wrap this somehow in a Parallel.ForEach loop or is that wrong etc..

Comment: 3 million because `tr1` has 3 million entries? This should parallelize nicely, since you are not sharing data (think of partitioning your data and running the loop over smaller sets of data). However the code makes it difficult to see for sure as its difficult to figure out what is going on.

Comment: @peeyush singh Yes tr1 has 3 million entries. You mean, Partitioning the data and start new Threads which I know how to do already? I have benchmarked other tests before using new Threads. But it seems to only be possible to start 4 new threads and get a speed x 4. Starting more than 5 threads starts to decrease the performance instead. It seems that threads are isolated to ONE core and doesn't use all 24 cores that I have?

Comment: Ideally as you are beginner I would just leave it to the dot net framework class to create/schedule threads (parrallel extension should do it). I would expect it to spin 1 thread per core. But that's all I can advice, start with the simple and then try to put in modifications. MSDN/documentation is your friend. Also not sure if your data structures are optimal, with a large number or iterations be careful where to use list or dictionary or some other structure.

Comment: That is the problem I have I beleive, I also have a feeling that "parrallel extension should do it" but I am afraid that I am just as stuck in that knowing and not sure how to implement this. (I will look over the data structures also and see if that could be better but beleive that is another thing then)

Comment: note, all this `num1` stuff look completely redundant , and the worst names you could ever give them

Comment: I think this should go to code review

Comment: Please don't get stuck on the code itself if not needed. My question is about how to approach something like this with for example Parallel.ForEach

Answer (score 0):

I did put the Parallel.ForEach loop in the code. I also noticed that I "had to??" put a lock object as the below lists seem to get completely messed up as it were sharing the variables with other threads.

```
if (calc1 > 0) { plusLIST2.Add(str); }
else
{
    minusLIST2.Add(str);
}
```

It seems that Parallel.ForEach is not threadsafe?

***When this code runned it took: 62 seconds -vs- 57 seconds with a single loop.***

Should it not be possible to do this faster with 24 cores?
I know the lock object blocks the code also which is a "bottleneck" for the code to run freely?

```
        public void calculationFunction(Dictionary<String, List<String>> tr1, Dictionary<String, List<ArrayList>> v1, Dictionary<String, bool> v5,
                                        Dictionary<String, int> infoIndex, out List<String> minusLIST, out List<String> plusLIST)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
            double num1 = 0; double num2 = 0; double num3 = 0; double number1 = 0; double number2 = 0; double number3 = 0; double thenum1 = 0; double thenum2 = 0; double thenum3 = 0;
            double NUM1 = 0; double NUM2 = 0; double NUM3 = 0; double NUMBER1 = 0; double NUMBER2 = 0; double NUMBER3 = 0; String str = ""; String num11 = ""; String num22 = ""; String num33 = "";
            String number11 = ""; String number22 = ""; String number33 = ""; double calc1 = 0;
            minusLIST = new List<String>(); plusLIST = new List<String>();
            List<String> minusLIST2 = new List<String>(); List<String> plusLIST2 = new List<String>(); object lockobj = new object();


            Parallel.ForEach(tr1, entry =>
            {
                List<String> allparams = new List<String>(entry.Value);
                if (allparams.Count == 10)
                {
                    if (v5.ContainsKey(allparams[7]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[8]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[9]))
                    {
                        if (v5[allparams[7]] && v5[allparams[8]] && v5[allparams[9]])
                        {
                            //Calculate both calc scenarios!
                            num1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][0]; number1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][1]; thenum1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][2];
                            num2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][0]; number2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][1]; thenum2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][2];
                            num3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][0]; number3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][1]; thenum3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][2];

                            NUM1 = num1; NUM2 = num2; NUM3 = num3; NUMBER1 = number1; NUMBER2 = number2; NUMBER3 = number3;
                            if (num1 <= 0 || number1 <= 0) { NUM1 = thenum1; NUMBER1 = thenum1; }
                            if (num2 <= 0 || number2 <= 0) { NUM2 = thenum2; NUMBER2 = thenum2; }
                            if (num3 <= 0 || number3 <= 0) { NUM3 = thenum3; NUMBER3 = thenum3; }
                            if (NUM1 > 0 && NUM2 > 0 && NUM3 > 0 && NUMBER1 > 0 && NUMBER2 > 0 && NUMBER3 > 0)
                            {
                                lock (lockobj)
                                {
                                    str = ""; num11 = ""; num22 = ""; num33 = ""; number11 = ""; number22 = ""; number33 = "";
                                    if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0 && number3 > 0) { } else { str = string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum1) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum2) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum3); }

                                    if (num1 <= 0) { num11 = "0"; num1 = thenum1; } else { num11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num1); }
                                    if (num2 <= 0) { num22 = "0"; num2 = thenum2; } else { num22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num2); }
                                    if (num3 <= 0) { num33 = "0"; num3 = thenum3; } else { num33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num3); }
                                    if (number1 <= 0) { number11 = "0"; number1 = thenum1; } else { number11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number1); }
                                    if (number2 <= 0) { number22 = "0"; number2 = thenum2; } else { number22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number2); }
                                    if (number3 <= 0) { number33 = "0"; number3 = thenum3; } else { number33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number3); }


                                    //Calculate
                                    if (allparams[6] == "0")
                                    {
                                        calc1 = ((num1 * number2 * number3) - 45) / 10;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        calc1 = (((num1 * number2) / number3) + 45) / 10;
                                    }

                                    //String
                                    str = calc1 + "," + allparams[0] + " - " + allparams[1] + " - " + allparams[2] + "," +
                                                                         allparams[3] + " - " + allparams[4] + " - " + allparams[5] + "," +
                                                                         num11 + " / " + num22 + " / " + num33 + "," +
                                                                         number11 + " / " + number22 + " / " + number33 + "," +
                                                                         str + "," +
                                                                         calc1 + "%";

                                    if (calc1 > 0) { plusLIST2.Add(str); }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        minusLIST2.Add(str);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            plusLIST = new List<String>(plusLIST2);
            minusLIST = new List<String>(minusLIST2);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to run the code in a: "Parallel.ForEach(tr1, entry =>" loop.
When I did declare all variables INSIDE the loop. The variables didn't get mixed up in the threads now. Also I needed to put a lock object when .Add to the 2 lists.

***Now it took 12 seconds(Parallel.ForEach) -VS- 57 seconds(Single for loop)
So this is an improvement by 4.75 times.***

**But still, I do have 24 cores so I wonder why it doesn't go for example at least 15-20 times faster?**

What can I do in order to use as many as possible/all cores?

```
public void calculationFunction(Dictionary<String, List<String>> tr1, Dictionary<String, List<ArrayList>> v1, Dictionary<String, bool> v5,
                                Dictionary<String, int> infoIndex, out List<String> minusLIST, out List<String> plusLIST)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

    minusLIST = new List<String>(); plusLIST = new List<String>();
    List<String> minusLIST2 = new List<String>(); List<String> plusLIST2 = new List<String>(); object lockobj = new object();


    Parallel.ForEach(tr1, entry =>
    {
        List<String> allparams = new List<String>(entry.Value);
        if (allparams.Count == 10)
        {
            if (v5.ContainsKey(allparams[7]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[8]) && v5.ContainsKey(allparams[9]))
            {
                if (v5[allparams[7]] && v5[allparams[8]] && v5[allparams[9]])
                {
                    double num1 = 0; double num2 = 0; double num3 = 0; double number1 = 0; double number2 = 0; double number3 = 0; double thenum1 = 0; double thenum2 = 0; double thenum3 = 0;
                    double NUM1 = 0; double NUM2 = 0; double NUM3 = 0; double NUMBER1 = 0; double NUMBER2 = 0; double NUMBER3 = 0; String str = ""; String num11 = ""; String num22 = ""; String num33 = "";
                    String number11 = ""; String number22 = ""; String number33 = ""; double calc1 = 0;

                    //Calculate both calc scenarios!
                    num1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][0]; number1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][1]; thenum1 = (double)v1[allparams[0]][infoIndex[allparams[7]]][2];
                    num2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][0]; number2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][1]; thenum2 = (double)v1[allparams[1]][infoIndex[allparams[8]]][2];
                    num3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][0]; number3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][1]; thenum3 = (double)v1[allparams[2]][infoIndex[allparams[9]]][2];

                    NUM1 = num1; NUM2 = num2; NUM3 = num3; NUMBER1 = number1; NUMBER2 = number2; NUMBER3 = number3;
                    if (num1 <= 0 || number1 <= 0) { NUM1 = thenum1; NUMBER1 = thenum1; }
                    if (num2 <= 0 || number2 <= 0) { NUM2 = thenum2; NUMBER2 = thenum2; }
                    if (num3 <= 0 || number3 <= 0) { NUM3 = thenum3; NUMBER3 = thenum3; }
                    if (NUM1 > 0 && NUM2 > 0 && NUM3 > 0 && NUMBER1 > 0 && NUMBER2 > 0 && NUMBER3 > 0)
                    {


                        str = ""; num11 = ""; num22 = ""; num33 = ""; number11 = ""; number22 = ""; number33 = "";
                        if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && number1 > 0 && number2 > 0 && number3 > 0) { } else { str = string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum1) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum2) + " / " + string.Format("{0:F10}", thenum3); }

                        if (num1 <= 0) { num11 = "0"; num1 = thenum1; } else { num11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num1); }
                        if (num2 <= 0) { num22 = "0"; num2 = thenum2; } else { num22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num2); }
                        if (num3 <= 0) { num33 = "0"; num3 = thenum3; } else { num33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", num3); }
                        if (number1 <= 0) { number11 = "0"; number1 = thenum1; } else { number11 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number1); }
                        if (number2 <= 0) { number22 = "0"; number2 = thenum2; } else { number22 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number2); }
                        if (number3 <= 0) { number33 = "0"; number3 = thenum3; } else { number33 = string.Format("{0:F10}", number3); }


                        //Calculate
                        if (allparams[6] == "0")
                        {
                            calc1 = ((num1 * number2 * number3) - 45) / 10;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            calc1 = (((num1 * number2) / number3) + 45) / 10;
                        }

                        //String
                        str = calc1 + "," + allparams[0] + " - " + allparams[1] + " - " + allparams[2] + "," +
                                                             allparams[3] + " - " + allparams[4] + " - " + allparams[5] + "," +
                                                             num11 + " / " + num22 + " / " + num33 + "," +
                                                             number11 + " / " + number22 + " / " + number33 + "," +
                                                             str + "," +
                                                             calc1 + "%";

                        if (calc1 > 0)
                        {
                            lock (lockobj) { plusLIST2.Add(str); }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lock (lockobj) { minusLIST2.Add(str); }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    plusLIST = new List<String>(plusLIST2);
    minusLIST = new List<String>(minusLIST2);
}
```